# VB.NET Datagridveiw cant select cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Sorry the name of this question is a bit confusing but i don't know any better way to word it.

I have a `Datagridview` table and i need to change the value of one cell on command, i have done this previously without an issue but i keep gettting an error with a certain cell name

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(OrderIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index).Value
```

This one works .

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(StatusDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index).Value
```

This one doesn't .

any help?
Both fields exist in the table aswell

Comment: Just specify the index of the cell like DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value

Comment: Would that still work if the DataGridView was re-ordered?

Comment: re-ordered in what way? if you re-ordered the columns then it wouldn't work. But you can also use the column name like DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("name_of_column").Value. This would work even if you re-order your columns.

Comment: The datagridview is the main screen of the app and it allows for column reordering while the app is running, I'll try the name of the column just to be safe